# How to find intersection of two events dependant on another event?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If A and B are independent, is this true? Why or why not?

P(A and B |C) = P(A|C) * P(B|C)

Comment: are are the conditional probabilities sum greater than 100%

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: **Hint**$$P(D|C)={P(D\cap C)\over P(C)}\\ P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider tossing of two fair coins independently. Let $A$ be the event that both outcomes are Heads or both outcomes are Tails, $B$ the event that the first toss results in Heads and $C$ the event that the second toss results in Heads. Then you can verify that these events are pairwise independent but $\frac 1 4=P(A\cap B \cap C) \neq \frac 1 8= P(A)P(B)P(C)$. Your equation becomes $\frac  {P(A\cap B \cap C)} {P(C)} =P(A)P(B)$. This is a contradiction.